# Using Try Catch: Why Is Query Result Set Inconsistent each time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am getting inconsistent numbers when I run the below code, sometimes 1 record off, other times 5 records off.

I am trying to get data from a temp table to a final or new table. The data in the temp table contained multiple records for each member. Each time a member visits, a new `count number` is inserted into the table with the memberID. This is an INT data type. If a member visits 10 times, then they will have numbers from 1 to 10, with ten being the most recent visit.

I am trying to get the most recent visit and insert into a new table but I need to roll back if an error occur.

Note: I am `Raising Error` because this code will be placed in an `SSIS TSQL Task`, the Raise error will make the task stop if the code fails.

```
USE MyDB;

GO

BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);
    DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;
    DECLARE @ErrorState INT;

    WITH Member
         AS (SELECT [MemberID],
                    [LocationID],
                    [CancelledDate],
                    [VisitCount],
                    [VisitDate],
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MemberID 
                                           ORDER BY [VisitDate] DESC) AS RowNumber
             FROM   [MySchema].[TempMemberTable]
             WHERE  MemberID IS NOT NULL
                    AND LocationID = '121')
    INSERT INTO [MySchema].[NewMemberTable]
                ([MemberID],
                 [LocationID],
                 [CancelledDate],
                 [VisitCount],
                 [VisitDate])
    SELECT [MemberID],
           [LocationID],
           [CancelledDate],
           [VisitCount],
           [VisitDate]
    FROM   Member
    WHERE  RowNumber = 1
           AND [CancelledDate] > GETDATE();

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@ERROR > 0
      BEGIN
          ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
      END

    SELECT @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
           @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
           @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();

    RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage,@ErrorSeverity,@ErrorState );
END CATCH;
```

Why is the result not consistent, even though the source data has not changed?

Comment: Every time you run it `GETDATE()` will be different. Also any duplicate values for `MemberID, VisitDate`?

Comment: There are no actual duplicates, however there are multiple instances of a record with different visit counts and dates But with same ID. The result changes each time I hit execute and the data is not live. I also tried `> CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)` same issues.

Comment: Try capturing the actual execution plans. When you get two runs with different row counts look at the actual row count on the plan operators and see where they differ.

Comment: What is the data type of VisitDate? Does it include time-of-day and is the time filled in, i.e. not always midnight? Is there a reason that you didn't include the CancelledDate condition inside the CTE rather than after it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a date in the QUERY.  Are you sure you are not adding additional rows since the WHERE clause might be adding data as time runs by?

Also, other isolation levels have dirty reads, unrepeatable reads, and phantom reads.  This all has to do with others changing the data at the time you grab it.  You are not alone on the system!

See matrix in this article.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378149.aspx

If you turn on snapshot isolation and the same inconsistencies happen, then it is the date or something in the TSQL code.  However, it looks straight forward enough.

Logical Order of SELECT statement.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx

```
1-FROM
2-ON
3-JOIN
4-WHERE
5-GROUP BY
6-WITH CUBE or WITH ROLLUP
7-HAVING
8-SELECT
9-DISTINCT
10-ORDER BY
11-TOP
```

The same logic and be achieved with a Derived Table.  The table has Member Id and Max Visit Date.  A full join brings back the most recent records.

```
-- Run Select Statemnt 5 Times
SELECT 
 [MemberID]
,[LocationID]
,[CancelledDate]
,[VisitCount]
,[VisitDate]
FROM [MySchema].[TempMemberTable] as T
JOIN
(
    SELECT MemberID as var_MemberID, Max([VisitDate]) as var_VisitDate
    FROM [MySchema].[TempMemberTable] 
    WHERE LocationID = '121'
) as D
WHERE T.[MemberID] = D.var_MemberID and T.[VisitDate] = D.var_VisitDate
GO 5
```

**Does this query executed 5 times give you different results?**

I purposely left off this additional filter

AND T.[CancelledDate] > GETDATE();

Comment: No, no one else is manipulating the data, the data is not live but it is in a large table. Thanks!

Comment: Basically, you are taking the most recent member by visit date that is in location 121 that has a cancel date > getdate().  Try moving the row number to the first field.  Also, put a ; in front of the CTE.

Comment: The changes in the result set are happening as I hit execute, each time I do, I get a different number of records return.

Comment: Hey my friend, I think this looks promising but I wanted to test it further. So far I am not seeing the same behavior but the result set did changed but remain the same. What are your thoughts?

Comment: Did you add back the CancelledDate or not.  That was where I though your issue is.  But a derived table might make more sense since you are throwing away the rownumber() value anyways.  There are many ways to solve a problem.